# Spammed Log Message involving pam_sm_authenticate and Kerberos

Tags: macos, logs, kerberos

Every minute this is logged in my system.log:

```
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Got user: andrew
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Got ruser: (null)
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Got service: sshd
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in od_principal_for_user(): No authentication authority returned
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in od_principal_for_user(): failed: 7
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Failed to determine Kerberos principal name.
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Done cleanup3
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Kerberos 5 refuses you
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): pam_sm_authenticate: ntlm
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Got user: andrew
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Got ruser: (null)
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Got service: sshd
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in od_principal_for_user(): No authentication authority returned
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in od_principal_for_user(): failed: 7
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Failed to determine Kerberos principal name.
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Done cleanup3
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Kerberos 5 refuses you
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): pam_sm_authenticate: ntlm
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Got user: andrew
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Got ruser: (null)
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Got service: sshd
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in od_principal_for_user(): No authentication authority returned
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in od_principal_for_user(): failed: 7
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Failed to determine Kerberos principal name.
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Done cleanup3
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Kerberos 5 refuses you
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): pam_sm_authenticate: ntlm
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Got user: andrew
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Got ruser: (null)
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Got service: sshd
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in od_principal_for_user(): No authentication authority returned
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in od_principal_for_user(): failed: 7
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Failed to determine Kerberos principal name.
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Done cleanup3
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Kerberos 5 refuses you
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): pam_sm_authenticate: ntlm
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Got user: andrew
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Got ruser: (null)
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Got service: sshd
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in od_principal_for_user(): No authentication authority returned
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in od_principal_for_user(): failed: 7
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Failed to determine Kerberos principal name.
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Done cleanup3
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Kerberos 5 refuses you
Aug 19 12:20:00 server.local java[66]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): pam_sm_authenticate: ntlm
```

I have turned ssh off (and I can confirm it is off). I have OSX Server installed and have the ftp and websites services turned on. I do have a few cron jobs that run every minute, but they shouldn't be using sshd, right?

What do these log messages mean?

Comment: What java programs are you running? grep the output os ps for java and search the launchd files for java

Comment: Could it possibly be Jenkins? I have it using my unix login database for authentication. Just thought of that.

Comment: That must be it because that is PID 66 (as hinted by java[66])

Comment: @Mark Do you think that these log messages are a problem?